# border-radius in SeaMonkey

Tags: css

I am working on a website of [digital signage](http://www.truknox.com), My boss want the website will look perfect in most of the browser like some common browser (Firefox, Chrome) and seaMonkey as well

I have used border-radius for these common browsers accordingly but i don't know the corner rounding for SeaMonkey.

Comment: The latest SeaMonkey doesn't need the `-moz-` prefix. Which version were you testing? PS Kudos to your boss for supporting SeaMonkey!

Comment: I am using seaMonkey 2.6.1. But i face this problem of gradient when i was was testing this website in seaMonkey 1.1.15 using "http://browsershots.org"

Comment: Gradient? That's another matter. But yes, with SeaMonkey versions below 2.1, you'll need the `-moz-` prefix. Note it's no problem to have both the versions with and without `-moz-` in the same CSS. And the `-webkit-` one. That way, you'll cover all the bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SeaMonkey is based on Gecko, just like Firefox.  Use `-moz-` prefixes for experimental and custom CSS properties.